# How can I select a radio button using jQuery without using its ID or value?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, radio-button

So, I'm working within a CMS where I have custom code to select a level of money derived from calculated age. This code is applicable over a broad range of forms and would work fine except I cannot control the values or id's of the money levels. The hierarchy stays the same from form to form, as do the donation-level-label-containers, the id's and values however change to a new 5 digit number with every new iteration.

```
<div class="donation-levels">
  <div class="donation-level-container">
    <div class="form-content">
      <div class="donation-level-input-container form-input">
        <div class="donation-level-label-input-container">
          <input type="radio" name="level_installmentexpanded" id="level_installmentexpanded16025"
value="16025"/>
        </div>
        <label for="level_installmentexpanded16025" onclick="">
        <div class="donation-level-amount-container"> $250.00 </div>
        <div class="donation-level-label-container"> Age 40 and under </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="level_installmentexpandedsubmit" id="level_installment_16025expandedsubmit" value="true" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="donation-level-container">
    <div class="form-content">
      <div class="donation-level-input-container form-input">
        <div class="donation-level-label-input-container">
          <input type="radio" name="level_installmentexpanded" id="level_installmentexpanded16022"
value="16022"/>
        </div>
        <label for="level_installmentexpanded16022" onclick="">
        <div class="donation-level-amount-container"> $230.00 </div>
        <div class="donation-level-label-container"> Age 41-60 </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="level_installmentexpandedsubmit" id="level_installment_16022expandedsubmit" value="true" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="donation-level-container">
    <div class="form-content">
      <div class="donation-level-input-container form-input">
        <div class="donation-level-label-input-container">
          <input type="radio" name="level_installmentexpanded" id="level_installmentexpanded16021"
value="16021"/>
        </div>
        <label for="level_installmentexpanded16021" onclick="">
        <div class="donation-level-amount-container"> $180.00 </div>
        <div class="donation-level-label-container"> Age 61-70 </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="level_installmentexpandedsubmit" id="level_installment_16021expandedsubmit" value="true" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="donation-level-container">
    <div class="form-content">
      <div class="donation-level-input-container form-input">
        <div class="donation-level-label-input-container">
          <input type="radio" name="level_installmentexpanded" id="level_installmentexpanded16026"
value="16026"/>
        </div>
        <label for="level_installmentexpanded16026" onclick="">
        <div class="donation-level-amount-container"> $140.00 </div>
        <div class="donation-level-label-container"> Age 71-79 </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="level_installmentexpandedsubmit" id="level_installment_16026expandedsubmit" value="true" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Using relative selectors or some other voodoo, can I set up a means by which to select these dynamically without having to change the ID every time it's applied to a new form?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: do you have its name?  i'm not sure which radio button you want but you can select things by their name, too

Comment: @mplungjan that's close, but doesn't let me differentiate between the different levels, I need to select just one at a time.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin name as in `name="level_installmentexpandedsubmit"`? That's also system generated if that's what you mean

Comment: the problem with by name or class is that you may get more than one result back so you'll have to loop through or use another piece of identifying info to get the exact one.  check out the answers below; they cover almost every possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well, most of you ignored the prerequisites of my question it seems like. What eventually worked for me here was as follows.

Since I'm using jQuery, I used the `:nth-child` CSS selectors to select each of these individually because since it's through jQuery, it works across browsers. I did like so to check the second input:

```
     $j("div.donation-levels div:nth-child(2) div div input").prop('checked',true);
```

I noticed it seemed like I left a div out (though through descendant selection it works anyways) because it did not in fact work for my first one, for which I used:

```
     $j("div.donation-levels div:first-child div div div input").prop('checked',true);
```

With a more specific hierarchy and the `:first-child` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help you,

```
$('.donation-level-label-input-container input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

or simply like,

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this just apply to all of the radio buttons? I need to be able to select one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

select by name or value:

```
 $("input[name=" + rbtname + "][value=" + yourVal + "]").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Value (as stated in the question title) and name are moot, they're the same or system generated and can't be used to select a specific button, unless I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all radio by:

```
$('input[type="radio"]')
```

or by name

```
 $('input[name="level_installmentexpanded"]')
```

get checked:

```
$('input[name="level_installmentexpanded"]:checked')
```

Comment: how about... input, with the name `level_installmentexpandedsubmit` that is type=radio?

Comment: I don't want to select all of the radio buttons whether by input type or name, since that won't let me choose a specific level, and I need to select them before they can be checked.

Comment: If you get by type, you will recive all input on page, but if you get by name, you will recive only radio in specific name

Comment: Right, but if you look at my code above, the system generates them all with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can select by class $('.class_name'), by tag $('tag_name'), by attribute name $('[attribute]'), by attribute value $('[attr=""]') and combinations of them. Just have a look at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

You can find radio button as:

**For checked radio:**

```
// Direct access
jQuery(':radio:checked')

// or by targeting a parent
jQuery('#a_form').find(':radio:checked');
// or
jQuery('#a_form').find(':radio').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
   // Do for checked
  } else {
   // other else
  }
})

// or directly find unchecked radio
jQuery(':radio:not(:checked)').each(function(){
  var t = $(this);
})
```

Comment: well, this won't work because I need to select them so they can be checked. That's the entire point, thanks though.